# Destruct Python List as Function Arguments

Tags: python, arrays, function, arguments

How to destruct array to argument list like in javascript?

```py
def foo( arg0, arg1 ): pass
bar = [ 32, 44 ]
foo( ...bar )
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's called argument unpacking. Use the `*args` format

```
foo(*bar)
```

More info: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/